# configure multiple databases in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How can I configure (and use) multiple databases in Zend Framework 2? Currently I have this in my global.php:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=my_db;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => '******',
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

But I do not see a way to add a second one.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you look at the Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory, you'll see that your adapter configuration points to only one key `'db'`. Which means that the Adapter that it builds will always use this (unique) configuration key.

I recommend you to create your own factory that would look like this :

```
namespace Your\Namespace;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

class MyAdapterFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

  protected $configKey;

  public function __construct($key)
  {
      $this->configKey = $key;
  }

  public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
  {
      $config = $serviceLocator->get('Config');
      return new Adapter($config[$this->configKey]);
  }
}
```

In your main module (or any other one), add the following to the Module.php file to declare the adapters factories to the Zend Service Manager:

```
use Your\Namespace\MyAdapterFactory;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface;

class Module implements ServiceProviderInterface{

//Previous code

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'myadapter1'        => new MyAdapterFactory('dbconfigkey1'),
            'myadapter2'        => new MyAdapterFactory('dbconfigkey2'),
            ),
       );

}

//...
```

The global config should now look like:

```
return array(
'dbconfigkey1' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=my_db;host=localhost',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => '******',
),

'dbconfigkey2' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=my_db2;host=localhost',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => '******',
),

);
```

to use the adapters you need to call them using the Service Manager:

```
$adapter1=$serviceManager->get('myadapter1');
$adapter2=$serviceManager->get('myadapter2');
```

## As of version 2.2

An Abstract Service Factory is now part of the zf2 Zend\Db module. It is possible to add multiples configuration keys under the 'adapters' sub-key :

```
'db'=> array(
    'adapters'=>array(
        'adapter' => array(
            'driver'         => 'Pdo',
            'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost',
            'username' => 'readCredential',
            'password' => '****'
        ),
        'adapter2' => array(
            'driver'         => 'Pdo',
            'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost',
            'username' => 'rwCredential',
            'password' => '****'
        ),
    )
),
```

However, the AbstractServiceFactory need to be added "manually" as it isn't so by default :

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
    )
),
```

The adapters are accessible as previously :

```
$adapter1=$serviceManager->get('adapter');
$adapter2=$serviceManager->get('adapter2');
```

From a performance perspective this second approach is better : One object will be instantiated (The abstract factory) to (potentially) create the different adapters. Whereas in the previous approach, one object per configuration was created.

Comment: Has this kind of strategy changed in 2.1?

Comment: After a quick look over the Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory I don't think so.

Answer (score 5):

I found much better explaination on https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/zend-framework-2-multiple-named-db-adapter-instances-using-adapters-subkey/

Zend Framework 2.2 comes with abstract_factories `Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory` that allow us to configure multiple named DB adapter instances. This is step by step to do it  :

1. Register `Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory` at ‘abstract_factories’ type under ‘service_manager’ key.

   //config/autoload/global.php
   //.... part of config/autoload/global.php
       'service_manager' => array( 
           'abstract_factories' => array(
               'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
           ),
       ),
2. Configure ‘adapters’ subkey under ‘db’ key at `config/autoload/global.php`

//config/autoload/global.php
//.... part of config/autoload/global.php

```
'db' => array(
    'adapters' => array(

        'db1' => array(
           'driver'         => 'Pdo',
           'dsn'             => 'mysql:dbname=zf2_staging;host=localhost',
           'driver_options'  => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
            ),
        ),

        'db2' => array(
           'driver'         => 'Pdo',
           'dsn'             => 'mysql:dbname=zf2_test;host=localhost',
           'driver_options'  => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

3. Configure ‘adapters’ subkey under ‘db’ key at `config/autoload/local.php`

//config/autoload/local.php

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'adapters' => array(
            'db1' => array(
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
            ),
            'db2' => array(
                'username' => 'other_user',
                'password' => 'other_user_passwd',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

3. Call adapter using ‘db1’ or ‘db2’ as db adapter from ServiceManager

   $sm->get('db1');

   $sm->get('db2');

If you need to get `$sm->get(‘Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter’)` as primary adapter, ‘db1’ and ‘db2’ as other adapter for specific purpose, then you need to define primary adapter directly under db, so the configuration of `config/autoload/global.php` will be like the following :

//config/autoload/global.php

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        //this is for primary adapter....
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'             => 'mysql:dbname=zf21_learn;host=localhost',
        'driver_options'  => array(
             PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
         ),

        //other adapter when it needed...
        'adapters' => array(

            'db1' => array(
               'driver'         => 'Pdo',
               'dsn'             => 'mysql:dbname=zf2_staging;host=localhost',
               'driver_options'  => array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
                ),
            ),
            'db2' => array(
               'driver'         => 'Pdo',
               'dsn'             => 'mysql:dbname=zf2_test;host=localhost',
               'driver_options'  => array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
                ),
            ),

        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        // for primary db adapter that called
        // by $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                    => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
        // to allow other adapter to be called by
        // $sm->get('db1') or $sm->get('db2') based on the adapters config.
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

The `config/autoload/global.local.php` should be configured too like the following :

//config/autoload/local.php

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        // for primary db adapter that called
        // by $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',

        // to allow other adapter to be called by
        // $sm->get('db1') or $sm->get('db2') based on the adapters config.
        'adapters' => array(
            'db1' => array(
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
            ),
            'db2' => array(
                'username' => 'other_user',
                'password' => 'other_user_passwd',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```