# Zend Framework 2 multiple databases

Tags: zend-framework2

How to configure Zend Framework 2 project to work with multiple databases?
I have followed the answer in [configure multiple databases in zf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003187/configure-multiple-databases-in-zf2)

I created my own factory as MyProject/module/MyModuleName/src/MyModuleName/Classes/MyAdapterFactory.php. Is this a correct path to create the file?

I couldn't figure out where should I call:
$adapter1=$serviceManager->get('myadapter1');
$adapter2=$serviceManager->get('myadapter2');

And also I cant ask for more clarifications since the question is 'protected' and I'm a noob.

Thank you in advance and please save my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a better path would be `modules/$Module/src/$Module/Db/Adapter/MyAdapterFactory.php`, in conjuction with the `namespace $Module\Db\Adapter` (of course not "$Module".. ;) )

The examples of `$serviceManager->get('myadapterX')` are merely examples. Anywhere you have access to the ServiceManager you can call these adapter. On the controller level you'd do it this way:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('myadapterX');
```

On configuration level when defining a TableGateway or such, it'd probably look something like this:

```
'my\Table\Gateway' => function ($sm) {
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('myadapterX');
    $gateway   = new Gateway($dbAdapter);
    return $gateway;
}
```