# DB connection with multiple Databases in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, adapter

Is it possible to establish a DB connection with multiple Databases in **Zend framework 2**?

How to establish multiple DB connection using Zendframework 2?

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a Module.php when creating getServiceConfig() function (Add one variable name in the place of adapter name) as below :

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{   
   return array(
      'factories' => array(                     
         'NameSpace\Model\YourTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('YourTableGateway');
                $table = new YourTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
          },
          'YourTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $adapter = $sm->get($this->dynamic_adapter);                    
                return new TableGateway('your_table_name', $adapter, null, null);
          },

 ),
);
```

Assign the value for **$this->dynamic_adapter** from controller,  which adapter need to change as per our requirements. (For me, based on the value fetched from  my table used by my Static DB adapter).

Refer below link to configure multiple DB adapter to your application:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17969889/2190889