# Dynamic connection to DB in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have 3 type of databases:

- Authen DB (fixed address and fixed schema)
- Config DB (fixed address and fixed schema)
- Service DBs (dynamic address and dynamic schema based on each service)

After users logined and verified via **Authen DB**.

Based on the information store in **Config DB**, all actions in ZF2 application relate to the service should be done on the correlative **Service DBs**.

Does ZF2 support this case? How can I solve this?

---

Below codes are my global.php and local.php.

global.php

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        // primary database
        'driver'    => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'       => 'mysql:host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;dbname=db_authen',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'",
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        ),
        // other database
        'adapters' => array(
            'db_config' => array(
               'driver'         => 'Pdo',
               'dsn'            => 'mysql:host=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy;dbname=db_config',
               'driver_options' => array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'",
                    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        // primary database
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
            'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory'
        ),
        // other database
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

local.php

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        // primary database
        'username' => '*****',
        'password' => '*****',

        // other database
        'adapters' => array(
            'db_config' => array(
                'username' => '*****',
                'password' => '*****',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14012520/131824

Comment: @DavidWeinraub: I maybe wrong but I think that the answer uses static declaration (the server host and schema are fixed) in local.php and global.php.

Comment: Yeah, you might be right: multiple adapters, but still static. Your need is for a dynamic adapter for the Service DB, right? I would probably instantiate those dynamic adapters manually using the creds you got from the Config DB. Still, there  must be a way for you to at least tell the service manager how to create an adapter *factory* (to which you could pass your dynamic creds) that creates adapters. </handwaving>

Comment: Yes. So, I'm finding a simple way to overwrite or create an adapter factory or something similars. I'm new to ZF2.

Comment: Maybe we should continue this [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92921/zend-framework-zf1-zf2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you do your authentication against the (statically configured) Auth DB and consult the (statically configured) Config DB for the dynamic information you need for the Service DB, you could probably instantiate yourself the correct DB-adapter for the Service DB, using something like:

```
// Config from the Config DB, packaged into an array with keys that 
// are expected by \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter
$config = [
    'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql', // for example
    'user' => 'my-dynamically-obtained-user',
    'password' => 'my-dynamically-obtained-password',
    'database' => 'my-dynamically-obtained-db-name',
    // etc
];
$adapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config);

// Now use the $adapter to build queries
$statement = $adapter->query('SELECT * FROM `mytable`');
$results = $statement->execute();

// iterate over the results, etc.
```

Alternatively, you could feed the `$adapter` into a model object you create that hides the db-specific query details from the consumer.

See [ZF2 docs for \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html)