# How to connect multiple db connection in ZF2 using PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, zend-framework2

The scenario is I have connected db in global.php like this

```
return array(
  'db' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=qflow;host=dbhostname.com',
    'driver_options' => array(
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
  ),
  'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
      'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
              => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
    ),
  )
);
​
```

​using usename password from local.php
​
​connecting successfully now I have another file in a module api.php and I am connecting another data base in it like this:

```
define('DB_USER', 'dbuser');
define('DB_PASS', 'password');


function connection() {
    global $DB;

    //persistent connection to database
    $DB = new PDO('mysql:host=dbhost.com;dbname=dbname;charset=UTF8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
}
```

When I am trying to connect it says pdo exception connection refused.
​I am wondering is it possible to connect 2 databases like this in ZF2? If so then how?
​

Comment: may be i want to know can we use 2 databases in one application ?

Comment: Yeah you can use multiple databases in one application.

Comment: Checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33102197/3283363

Comment: thanks, it helped a lot.