# Multiple Database connections - Zendframework

Tags: database, connection, zend-framework3

I want to connect multiple database connections in Zendframework application. I am not able to find any live example of the same. It would help if someone can post an example of using multiple db connections.

Comment: what is the version of your Zend framework

Comment: Zendframework 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [configure multiple databases in zf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003187/configure-multiple-databases-in-zf2) -> Works the same in ZF3, be advised you're better of doing it in config than shown in answer, as in config it may be cached, and this answer won't be.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use this code:

```
// In config/autoload/global.php

'db' => [
    'adapters' => [
        'Application\Db\WriteAdapter' => [
            'driver' => 'Pdo',
            'dsn' =>   
 'mysql:dbname=application;host=canonical.example.com;charset=utf8',
        ],
        'Application\Db\ReadOnlyAdapter' => [
            'driver' => 'Pdo',
            'dsn'    => 
 'mysql:dbname=application;host=replica.example.com;charset=utf8',
          ],
       ],
    ],
```